# RangeError: Invalid string length in jsreport when data is 100k

Tags: javascript, node.js, jsreport

Last 2 day, I am trying to generate PDF using [jsreport](https://jsreport.net/learn/phantom-pdf) in nodejs environment. 
It is working fine for small size data. But unfortunately, It not working when data is around 100k. It showing

```
Unhandled rejection /data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:1495
data: bin/www:16035 - result += newView._.onRender ? newView._.onRender(itemResult, childView) : itemResult;
data: bin/www:16035 - ^
data: bin/www:16035 - RangeError: Invalid string length
data: bin/www:16035 - at renderWithViews (/data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:1495:79)
data: bin/www:16035 - at Object.renderContent [as render] (/data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:1363:13)
data: bin/www:16035 - at Tag.render (/data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:2324:24)
data: bin/www:16035 - at renderTag (/data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:655:26)
data: bin/www:16035 - at Object.eval [as fn] (eval at buildCode (/data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:2156:10), <anonymous>:33:2)
data: bin/www:16035 - at renderWithViews (/data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:1508:18)
data: bin/www:16035 - at Object.renderContent [as render] (/data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:1363:13)
data: bin/www:16035 - at Tag.render (/data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:2305:15)
data: bin/www:16035 - at renderTag (/data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:655:26)
data: bin/www:16035 - at Object.eval [as fn] (eval at buildCode (/data/bizsystem/service-report/node_modules/jsrender/jsrender-node.js:2156:10), <anonymous>:7:2)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf - try this module, i was getting same error. once i used this modules my error was resolved

Comment: share your report template and your input data, perhaps in jsreport playground